# WebSocket Onclose Status Code 1001 meaning Going Away mean exactly

Tags: websocket

I am using Web Sockets in my Application

While onclose event , i am getting the status code as 1001

As per this web site , the status code 1001 means Going Away

[WebSockets Status Codes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/websocket/websocket.xml#close-code-number-rules)

Please let me know what does the Status 1001 meaning (Going Away) mean exactly

Please let me know , thanks in advance .

Answer (score 34):

From [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

```
  1001 indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server
  going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.
```

Comment: I guess that there is no chance of server going down , please tell me what does browser having navigated away from a page means ?? Thank you very much .

Comment: If a browser has a websocket connection open and the user clicks a link that takes them to a different page, the WebSocket connection on the previous page is closed, often with the 1001/Going Away code

Comment: my page remains open, and i'm still getting the same exception code

Comment: something in the route might have changed or triggered then

Comment: how do we increase default connection timeout?