# Cannot get response message when using the microsoft translator speech API

Tags: api, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I created a Microsoft Translator Speech API Service on Microsoft Azure for free . But When I was running the sample project with this service, there was no response message in the web socket. I'm sure the connection was established and the audio file was tansferred to the destination URL. The client program just waited until timeout and nothing received. The return code is 1001.

I want to ask what's wrong with my service and why the service doesn't response. The sample project is on 'https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Java-Speech-Translate'.

Here is the output of my program.

[image: Here is the output of my program.]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions. This will help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will read it and ask good questions next time.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105386/websocket-onclose-status-code-1001-meaning-going-away-mean-exactly) to an explanation of an error 1001.

Give it a try again and if needed, you can refer to the [Microsoft Translator Speech API documentation](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com).

Hope this helps.